# Does LexicalEnvironment’s [[outerEnv]] refer to the VariableEnvironment(of same Execution Context)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

In the function below, Does LexicalEnvironment’s [[outerEnv]] refer to the VariableEnvironment(the VariableEnvironment which belongs to the same Execution Context).

Or LE,VE are same and their [[outerEnv]] both refer to global EnvironmentRecord？

```
function fun(){
  let a = 1
  var b = 2
}
```

Comment: "*refer to the VariableEnvironment*" - to **which** VariableEnvironment?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you, I have read many of your other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417158/how-will-the-lexical-environment-and-the-variable-environment-will-look-like-at/69419481#69419481) and benefited from them. I draw a [picture](https://imgpp.com/image/ZXOuI) to describe my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Inside a function, `[[VariableEnvironment]]` and `[[LexicalEnvironment]]` both point to the same Environment Record, whose `[[outerEnv]]` points to the Environment Record inside which the function was created.

---

The `[[VariableEnvironment]]` internal property of an Execution Context points to the corresponding function scope, that is, the scope in which `var` and function declarations create their Bindings.

On the other hand, `[[LexicalEnvironment]]` points to the current block scope. That is where Bindings created by `let`, `const`, `class`, `catch` and `with` statements exist, and from where Binding lookups happen.

A new `[[LexicalEnvironment]]` is generated for each block, while there's only one `[[VariableEnvironment]]` created for an Execution Context.

On the topmost scope of functions (which have their own Execution Contexts), these two are the same, and indeed, they point to the same Environment Record. You can see this in *PrepareForOrdinaryCall*, which is evaluated before a function is called:

> ### [10.2.1.1 PrepareForOrdinaryCall ( *F*, *newTarget* )](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-prepareforordinarycall)
>
> The abstract operation PrepareForOrdinaryCall takes arguments *F* (a function object)
> and *newTarget* (an Object or **undefined**). It performs the following
> steps when called:
>
> 1. Let *callerContext* be the running execution context.
> 2. Let *calleeContext* be a new ECMAScript code execution context.
> 3. Set the Function of *calleeContext* to *F*.
> 4. Let *calleeRealm* be *F*.[[Realm]].
> 5. Set the Realm of *calleeContext* to *calleeRealm*.
> 6. Set the ScriptOrModule of *calleeContext* to *F*.[[ScriptOrModule]].
> 7. Let localEnv be NewFunctionEnvironment(*F*, *newTarget*).
> 8. **Set the LexicalEnvironment of *calleeContext* to *localEnv*.**
> 9. **Set the VariableEnvironment of *calleeContext* to *localEnv*.**
> 10. Set the PrivateEnvironment of *calleeContext* to *F*.[[PrivateEnvironment]].
> 11. If *callerContext* is not already suspended, suspend *callerContext*.
> 12. Push *calleeContext* onto the execution context stack; *calleeContext* is now the running execution context.
> 13. NOTE: Any exception objects produced after this point are associated with *calleeRealm*.
> 14. Return *calleeContext*.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

The `[[outerEnv]]` property of that Environment Record points to the `[[Environment]]` of the function, which is the Environment Record where the function was constructed.

The `[[outerEnv]]` of an Environment Record that is the `[[LexicalEnvironment]]` of an inner block, points to the Environment Record of the block it's inside of.

So, in your case, it would look like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
|    fun Execution Context    |
+-----------------------------+
|                             |        +----------------------+
|  [[LexicalEnvironment]] -----------> |  Environment Record  |
|                             |        +----------------------+
|  [[VariableEnvironment]] ----------> |                      |
|                             |        |  bindings: [         |
+-----------------------------+        |    a = 1,            |
                                       |    b = 2             |
                                       |  ]                   |
                                       |  [[outerEnv]] --+    |
                                       |                 |    |
                                       +-----------------|----+
+-----------------------------+                          |
|  Global Execution Context   |                          | 
+-----------------------------+                          v
|                             |        +----------------------+
|  [[LexicalEnvironment]] -----------> |  Environment Record  |
|                             |        +----------------------+
|  [[VariableEnvironment]] ----------> |                      |
|                             |        |  bindings: [         |
+-----------------------------+        |    fun = <Function>  |
                                       |  ]                   |
                                       |  [[outerEnv]] --+    |
                                       |                 |    |
                                       +-----------------|----+
                                                         |
                                                         v
                                                        null
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm confused with the [FunctionDeclarationInstantiation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)'s  20. It seems that if the function is no-strict, a new `Environment Record` whose `[[outerEnv]]` is the current `LE`  will be created. And then set `LE` to the new `Environment Record`.